# Yii. Не работает limit для реляционного запроса

Tags: php, yii

Есть 2 таблицы – Advert и Foto

связь

```
'fotos' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Foto', 'advert_id', 'limit'=>1),
```

запрос

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->order = 'id DESC';
$criteria->limit = 5;
$criteria->condition = 'has_foto=:has_foto';
$criteria->params = array(':has_foto'=>Advert::HAS_FOTO);
$lastAdverts = Advert::model()->with(array(
                'fotos'=>array(
                    'limit'=>1)
                ))->findAll($criteria);
```

Этот запос возвращает 5 записей (тут limit срабатывает) из Advert и кучу записей из Foto, хотя из Foto должно быть не больше пяти, т.к. limit=1.
Что я делаю не правильно?

И еще, почему вот этот код вызывает ошибку?

Код: Выделить всё

```
$foto = array();
            foreach ($lastAdverts as $advert) {
                $foto[] = $advert->fotos->id;  //вот тут  PHP notice Trying to get property of non-object
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка потому что Реляция fotos использует тип реляции HAS_MANY, и выводить его нужно массивом, к примеру так

```
foreach ($lastAdverts as $advert) {
     foreach($advert->fotos as $foto) {
       $foto[] = $advert->fotos->id;
     }
}
```

И сам лимит, измените критерию

```
$lastAdverts = Advert::model()->with(array('fotos'=>array('limit'=>1, 'together' => false)))->findAll($criteria);
```

[Читайте документацию](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.arr)